# Google/Facebook/Twitter share button add additional "class"

Tags: jquery, twitter, google-plus, facebook-sharer

I added three share buttons on my website (G+,FB,Twitter). 
Everything works fine, but I need also to take under control that moment when user click on any share button, share windows should appear but also, I'd like to run my jQuery script in the same time. Tried in different ways, but result is sad. Is it possible to add a "class" for those buttons?
Maybe someone tried to do the same before?

Need an advice.
Thank you
Kind Regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should consider looking at the events for each button.

[Facebook has a like event](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.Event.subscribe/):

```
FB.Event.subscribe('edge.create',
    function(response) {
        alert('You liked the URL: ' + response);
    }
);
```

[Twitter has a tweet event](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/intents/events):

```
twttr.events.bind('tweet', function(event) {
    // Do something there
});
```

[Google supports a callback attribute](https://developers.google.com/+/plugins/+1button/#plusonetag-parameters):

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://apis.google.com/js/plusone.js"></script>
<g:plusone callback="yourCallbackHandler"></g:plusone>
```

Comment: Thank you! But the problem is, that Google Share button doesn't support a callback function. But "+1" - is a little bit different.

Comment: I've never heard of it, but it does appear to support two events: `onstartinteraction` and `onendinteraction`. [Read more about them here.](https://developers.google.com/+/plugins/share/#sharetag-parameters)

Comment: Ok, much better. But still not what I was looking for. I just need to check, if the page is shared already. I didn't find such opportunity in Google Plus API, or maybe i'm blind? Or maybe there is a much easier way to do it?

Comment: You need to see if the user shared the page or if it has been shared before by anyone?

Comment: If the user shared page before.

Comment: You'll need to dig into the SDKs for that kind of data. Here's how you check a Facebook user, for example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11139035/how-to-check-if-user-shared-website-facebook-is-it-possible

Doesn't appear to be possible with Google+ though: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9681495/how-to-check-user-has-liked1-google-button-on-website-or-url

Comment: Yeah, I read it before. I don't like the idea that facebook & twitter will check if page is shared through their APIs, but Google Plus shares i'll check using my script. That's why i decided to do everything using my own code. I just need to think, how to add a "class" or "id" to the buttons and run my script with API together - that would be enough. But I don't think that is possible. What do you think?

Comment: You can't do what you're trying to do with Google+'s share button. Nor can you check with the API if a user has shared a resource. Sorry.